# Curious division result

Tags: c++

How can this code...

```cpp
vector<double> _pc;
vector<int> _documentClassIds;

[...]

someMemberFunction(vector<int> const & documentIds) {

  cout << "_pc[0] = "<< _pc[0]<<endl;
  cout << "_pc[1] = "<< _pc[1]<<endl;
  cout << "documentIds.size() = " << documentIds.size()<<endl;

  // Normalize
  for (auto documentId : documentIds)
    _pc[_documentClassIds[documentId]] =
    _pc[_documentClassIds[documentId]] / documentIds.size();
  cout << "_pc[0] = "<< _pc[0]<<endl;
  cout << "_pc[1] = "<< _pc[1]<<endl;
}
```

produce this output?

```
_pc[0] = 3
_pc[1] = 3
documentIds.size() = 6
_pc[0] = 0.0138889
_pc[1] = 0.0138889
```

Comment: What types are your containers?

Comment: Size is 6, so I would expect six divisions total.  If three of the classIds are 0 and three of the classIds are 1, then _pc[0] would be divided by 6, then another 6, then another 6.  3/(6*6*6) is 0.0138889.

Comment: OMG.  It is 2am. I should go to bed. Thank you.

Comment: Don't code tired. Inebriated is okay but tired should be avoided :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think the problem is.

You have *six* document IDs, so your `for` loop runs six times. Each time it runs, it divides one of your `_pc` array values by six.

Since `0.0138888...` is 3 divided by 216 (6^3), the calculations seem correct.

It's obvious that the selection of which `_pc` array entry to divide is equally distibuted so that each gets divided three times, so each ends up as:

```
(((3 / 6) / 6) / 6) => 0.013888...
```